# CrossGeolocator in Xamarin UWP project returns a wrong current location

Tags: xamarin, uwp, location

CrossGeolocator in my Xamarin UWP project returns a wrong current location. The location that it returns to me is Lakeville, Minnesota. But I am living much far away from it. Here is the code:

```
   var locator = CrossGeoLocator.Current;
   locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;
   var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), null, true);
```

Where is the problem? Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of UWP device are you using that has a GPS in it?

Comment: Just a windows desktop running vs

Comment: then it's probably using IP geolocation, which may or may not be very accurate, depending on a variety of factors

Comment: @renintx In that case, Windows is performing a "best guess" of your location based upon public Wi-Fi SSID mappings, IP address, etc.... It is most likely just using a GeoIP database to map your public Internet IP address to a location... i.e. Google shows my "location" 30 miles away from my physical location and Microsoft/Bing shows my location 20 miles away based solely on my public IP address, using WiFI SSID mapping, it is down under 1 mile, etc...

Comment: Please disable opened vpn and use the actual internet ip address to test again.

Comment: @Nico Zhu What do you mean "disable opened vpn"? How can I do it?

Comment: If your local network uses a VPN proxy, it will cause the map to find the corresponding location according to the proxy's ip address.

Comment: And if you have not use vpn, please try to open map app and set the default location.

Comment: @Nico Zhu I am working on VPN, so that might cause the issue. I think you are right, but right now I cannot try working without vpn. I will try that later. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CrossGeolocator in Xamarin UWP project returns a wrong current location

If your device does not contain GPS sensor, `CrossGeoLocator` api will get current location with IP address preferentially. If your local network uses a VPN proxy, it will cause the map to find the corresponding location according to the proxy's ip address that will make the location deviation from actual location.

> but right now I cannot try working without vpn.

If you can't use disable vpn. the better way is add the [GPS sensor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation?view=winrt-19041) to your device. It has a higher priority.